# Does "off" mean "from" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialect

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd6jCHI9C_M&t=3m24s) report, the man said:

> Who's making the most money *off* the deal.

Does *off* in this context mean *from*? and is this use common or just dialectal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means "from", and no, it's not dialect.

> **Make** [something] **off (of)** [something else]

is a phrasal verb, often used with money, or the suggestion of money.